# Hikari pool connection timeout issue for Java Vertx application

Tags: java, connection, vert.x, hikaricp, pooling

We are using an application on Java Vertx. We are using HikariCP for connection pooling with JDBC for Oracle database. This application works fine with certain number of TPS. But it started giving error if the concurrent load on application is high.

The error is coming like this.

*Connection silently closed by HikariCP .
Connection not available ...*

The other observation is this happens only for few seconds and then on next few seconds application started working as usual.

We are using connection pool with size of 30 for this application, should we increase the pool?
Please note, we have not noticed any connection leak with this application.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it turns out that connectionTimeout property was causing issues. So we have added oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout property into JVM arguments and it helped.